# Add onKeyDown Event on Varien Data Form Element in Magento

Tags: php, forms, magento, events

I'd like to add event on text element

```
    $barcodeFieldset = $form->addFieldset('form_barcode', array('legend' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Barcode Information')));

    $barcodeFieldset->addField('barcode', 'submit', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Barcode'),
        'name' => 'barcode',
        'onKeyDown' => "alert('x')",
        'required' => true,
        'note' => 'If You want to scan barcode, focus to this textfield.',
        $this->_isReadonly() => $this->_isReadonly(),
    ));
```

onKeyDown doesn't work. How to make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my idea.

```
    $barcodeFieldset = $form->addFieldset('form_barcode', array('legend' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Barcode Information')));

    $barcodeFieldset->addField('barcode', 'password', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Barcode'),
        'name' => 'barcode',
        'after_element_html' =>
                "<script type='text/javascript'>" .
                "$('barcode').setAttribute('onKeyDown', 'if(event.keyCode == 13){editForm.submit($(" . "edit_form" . ").action)};');"
                . "</script>",
        'required' => true,
        'note' => 'If You want to scan barcode, focus to this textfield.',
        $this->_isReadonly() => $this->_isReadonly(),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Magento does not allow this. Here are the attributes that you can specify on a submit element: `'type', 'title', 'class', 'style', 'onclick', 'onchange', 'disabled', 'readonly', 'tabindex'`. These come from `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract::getHtmlAttributes()`.
The only field type that allows onkeydown (written in lowercase) is the `link` field (`Varien_Data_Form_Element_Link`).

Comment: ouch! is there no way to trick it? because the behaviour of the barcode scanner is fill the text and ENTER. i must trigger it with onKeyDown. T_T

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano You can try to use the `link` type field, or create your own field that accepts the onkeydown attribute